# Read data from gridview 1 and generate data for gridview 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to compare data from an excel file to my database.

i have managed to import the excel file and display the data in a gridview.

Gridview1

id    name
1        ss
2   aa

now i want gridview2 to have get data from the database which has the same id.

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

GridView controls expose a RowDatabound event.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

> Before the GridView control can be rendered, each row in the control must be bound to a record in the data source. The RowDataBound event is raised when a data row (represented by a GridViewRow object) is bound to data in the GridView control. This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as modifying the values of the data bound to the row, whenever this event occurs.